# Unix egrep command with regular expression

Tags: grep, sh

Hi can somebody please tell me what does this expression mean

```
 ls -lrt *.txt|egrep -v " (*.?) (*.?) (*.?) 0 (*.?) (*.?) (*.?) "
```

any insight is very much appreciated.

Comment: I've never seen a case where parsing the output of `ls` was a good solution.  `find` is the tool that we use to find files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, please note that if someone is grepping the output of `ls`, it's almost certainly the wrong way to achieve the task.  `ls` is meant for human consumption, and `find` is probably the better tool.

It looks to me that the person is trying to find any files that have a size greater than zero.  If so, then the way that it should be done is:

```
find . -type f -size +0
```

Comment: Thanks ..would you kindly explain the meaning of individual terms in your command?

Comment: `-type f` says you want to find files, as opposed to directories, pipes, etc.  `-size +0` means to find sizes that are greater than 0.  Read the `find` man page for many many more options: `man find`.

Comment: @AsfakulIslam FYI explainshell.com is a good resource for finding meanings of commands and their flags that you come across, e.g. for this answer: http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find+.+-type+f+-size+%2B0

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -lrt
```

list files (`ls`), detailed view (`-l`), sorted backwards (`-r`) by modification time (`-t`)

```
ls -lrt *.txt
```

list all text files sorted by time, the output looks like this

```
$ ls -ltr 
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Mar  5  2012 selinux
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Apr 25  2012 srv
drwx------   2 root root  16K Feb  7  2013 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Feb  7  2013 cdrom
```

now you're grepping for all lines **except for** (`-v`) those with a zero in the 4th column, which I don't fully understand.

anyway, `(*.?)` would mean just any sequence of characters (zero or more)

Comment: Thanks I am confused by what the notation *.? mean?

Comment: I guess the regexp is broken. It looks like someone was trying to grep for a zero in some column, but the fixed number of spaces is weird. Can you elaborate what it is supposed to do?

Comment: it's working in the prod env. can you atleast tell me what does (*.?) mean??

Comment: just any sequence of characters (zero or more). parenthesis are just for grouping. it means, here are white spaces important.